# How to add Dynamic String value to String array in java

Tags: java

I have a string name called label,which is dynamically having values.I want to add this every time generated values into array list.

```
List<String> container = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(label));
```

I tried this way but its printing only the last value, where I'm doing wrong, any suggestion?

Comment: Label is String or String[]

Comment: How is this related to Android ? :\

Comment: Thanks for your response.label is String

Comment: @twntee i need to set the container value into spinner.

Comment: @RajeshDurai then also, I am sorry but as from your question it is not related to Android.

Answer (score 2):

In this every time the dynamically changing value of label will be added into the container.

```
       List<String> container = new ArrayList<String>();

        String label = "Sample1";
        container.add(label);

        label = "Sample2";
        container.add(label);

        label = "Sample3";
        container.add(label);

        System.out.println("container : "+container);
```

But you are creating new list every time. using the label variable

```
List<String> container = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(label));
```

Comment: @RajeshDurai you are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think everytime you are resetting your container variable by the declaration:

```
List<String> container = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(label));
```

Ideally you should do it only at first time, after that simply add the newly created label:

```
container.add(label);
```

Comment: Correct..thanks for your ans.